# We have a vector but is not clear which the constructor is called

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, boolean, std

which constructor is called here ?

```
std::vector<bool> v(256, false);
```

the container vector of four constructors:

```
default (1) 
explicit vector (const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
fill (2)    
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
range (3)   
template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
copy (4)    
vector (const vector& x);
```

and where is the boolean parameter in the constructor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This constructor will be called:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

`value_type` is typedef of an element type that vector contains. For `std::vector<bool>` value_type is `bool`. All 256 elements will be filled with `false` value.

From C++ reference:

val - Value to fill the container with. Each of the n elements in the container will be initialized to a copy of this value. Member type value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in vector as an alias of its first template parameter (T).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/